# python match over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a portion of a multi-line string.  Specifically, I'd like to pull out the list of terms between the center pair of braces:

```
'my datagroup 2.5 {\n    nose-capabilities {\n        none\n        slow\n        800\n        1200\n    }\n}\n'
```

I've tried this:

```
re.findall('.*{.*{(?:\s*(\S+)\s*)*}\s*}', d, re.S)

# ['1200']
```

So I'm only getting the last capture as far as I can tell.  ?

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: What are you looking for here?

Comment: I want this from the string:

    ['none', 'slow', '800', '1200']

Comment: Well, there's only one substring that has two open braces in it, so how did you expect to get more than one thing back from `findall`?

Comment: I clearly didn't understand findall well.  So if I want to return a group for every iterative match of the non-whitespace strings between the center pair of braces, I should be using match (knowing now that this is a hard-headed way to extract the list anyway)?

Comment: If you not so good at regular expressions, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27138518/4231346 is more preferable for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of `findall`. It returns one value for every match of the entire pattern. If you want multiple groups in one pattern, that's fine, but you don't need `findall` for that.

In fact, you really don't need that. You can just replace the whole middle of your pattern with `(.*?)` to trivially capture everything between the second open brace and the first close brace.

Note the non-greedy match; otherwise, it would suck up everything up to the *last* close brace, instead of up to the *first*. (You could use a lookahead assertion for this, but non-greedy matches are simpler.)

```
>>> re.findall('.*{.*{(.*?)}', d, re.S)
['\n        none\n        slow\n        800\n        1200\n    ']
```

Although of course `findall` still isn't doing you any good:

```
>>> re.search('.*{.*{(.*?)}', d, re.S).group(1)
'\n        none\n        slow\n        800\n        1200\n    '
```

Anyway, once you have that, you can just `split` it:

```
>>> re.search('.*{.*{(.*?)}', d, re.S).group(1).split()
['none', 'slow', '800', '1200']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this using regex, you would be better off using [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) and a lookahead assertion.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?s){(?!.*{)([^}]*)', d).group(1).split()
['none', 'slow', '800', '1200']
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for any number of nested braces:

```
s = 'my datagroup 2.5 {\n    nose-capabilities {\n        none\n        slow\n        800\n        1200\n    }\n}\n'
# the position of the inner brace
start = s.rfind('{') + 1
end = s.find('}')
# find alphanumeric characters in substring
re.findall('\w+', s[start:end])
```